# Can I retrieve an old WhatsApp account with a different phone number?

Tags: account-management, account-recovery, whatsapp

I have deleted my old WhatsApp account after changing my number thinking I can retrieve it once I set it up with my new number.  But I can't. I really need some of the messages from my old account...is there anyway I can get it back? I have tried to retrieve the account using my old number but they send me a code to the old number which I no longer have.